# Get webpage content with Hebrew characters / UTF-8

Tags: java, android, apache, hebrew

I'm trying to bring next webpage content (as it) to TextView in my android application.

http://www.kavim-t.co.il/include/getXMLStations.asp?parent=56_%20_2

Here are the results, Chrome vs Activity:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that Hebrew/UTF-8/Windows-1255 characters shown as "???".

I'm using next code (using org.apache.http):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, HTTP.UTF_8);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.kavim-t.co.il/include/getXMLStations.asp?parent=56_%20_2");

HttpResponse response = null;
response = client.execute(request);
BufferedReader rd = null;
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    tv.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the character set for the InputStreamReader

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: The link should target the Android documentation not the J2SE doc. Anyway this should be the correct answer (it it is really UTF-8 content).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge

Hebrew is supported in Android versions 2.2 and above.

If you are testing in device below 2.2 version than you will not able to see Hebrew text

Try to test in android version 2.2 and above

Comment: You are wrong. Hebrew is supported even in 2.1.    In addition, I'm writing for 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

This does somewhat completes the solutions given here (at least for Eclipse users).

If you're working with Eclipse and the console keeps showing '???????' instead of the UTF-8 non-English chars, follow the instructions in the following link (helped me after almost losing my mind about it):

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/